# NodeJS concatenation issue while iterating object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have following nodejs code. In which **commentedUser.user_id.image** variable inside loop over written in loop with **userImage** variable multiple time. I explained in detail with output.

```
for(var commentedUser of commentData){
    var userImage = (commentedUser.user_id.image=="")?"default.png":commentedUser.user_id.image;
    userImage = config.baseUrl+("upload/user/")+userImage;
    commentedUser.user_id.image = userImage;
}
successMessage.message = "Feed comment found successfully";
successMessage.data = commentData;
return response.send(JSON.stringify(successMessage));
```

**Output**

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "successfully",
    "data": [{
            "_id": "5c18d8403764675cccfb4de1",
            "feed_id": "5b9a19df682d9223606d3372",
            "comment": "Feed test comment",
            "user_id": {
                "_id": "5c18c20e7f936248e2b1b724",
                "role": "user",
                "image": "http://192.168.2.21:8046/upload/user/http://192.168.2.21:8046/upload/user/default.png"
            },
            "created_at": "2018-12-18T11:21:36.388Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5c19ccbad517491cfc1002ee",
            "feed_id": "5b9a19df682d9223606d3372",
            "comment": "Feed test comment",
            "user_id": {
                "_id": "5c18c20e7f936248e2b1b724",
                "role": "user",
                "image": "http://192.168.2.21:8046/upload/user/http://192.168.2.21:8046/upload/user/default.png"
            },
            "created_at": "2018-12-19T04:44:42.045Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

In output you can see **image url repeated** repeated which is the issue. I dont know why this happen. I tried for long time do not get success.

> Notes: **commentData** is an array of objects.

Comment: Your code adds the "base URL" and the path fragment `/upload/user` to the front of the image URLs, but it looks like the source URLs already include the base part.

Comment: What were the original values of `commentedUser.user_id.image`? And what is `config.baseUrl`?

Comment: @Pointy Not included already you can see that first I take image name then I concatenate with baseurl.

Comment: @Bergi original value of `commentedUser.user_id.image=blank(empty string)` and `config.baseUrl = common url` for all images

Comment: Well finding out exactly what happens in that loop is clearly the way to solve the problem.

Comment: @Pointy I try lots of from last 5 hour but not getting what an issue?

Comment: Well *what* have you tried? Have you added `console.log()` calls etc? What were the results? Without knowing what the source data looks like how do you think anybody can help?

Comment: @Sadikhasan In that case, you must be running the transformation multiple times on the same objects. In the first run, they become `http://192.168.2.21:8046/upload/user/default.png`, in the second run they get prefixed by `http://192.168.2.21:8046/upload/user/` again.

Comment: @Sadikhasan Maybe `successMessage.data[0].user === successMessage.data[1].user`?

Comment: @Pointy When I console `userImage` in loop it will print Only one url on first iteration and in second iteration it print concatenation issue

Comment: @Bergi No. There is no issue in `successMessage` When I debugging code I found issue with concatenation in loop statmement

Comment: @Sadikhasan If you `console.log(userImage)` at the end of the body of the loop, and it turns out a different value than the one in the final `JSON.stringify`, and also you get the expected value on the first log and the wrong value on the second log, that very strongly supports my hypothesis that the `.user` properties refer to the exact same object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Bergi's comment above. To state it in a different way: let's say you got these objects from a database (sql, mongodb, etc.); it's possible that the *two comments* you are looking at are both linked to the *same user id*. For that reason, even though you are looping through (example) 50 different comments, some of those comments might be running code on the same `user_id` object more than once.

A simple solution, for you, is just to make sure you don't normalize a URL that was already normalized, like this:

```
for(var commentedUser of commentData) {
    var userImage = (commentedUser.user_id.image=="")?"default.png":commentedUser.user_id.image;
    if (!userImage.startsWith("http")) {
        userImage = config.baseUrl+("upload/user/")+userImage;
    }
    commentedUser.user_id.image = userImage;
}
```

More generally, the fact you're running into this might be a sign you are doing this in the wrong spot - it probably should have happened further up the chain in your application, perhaps in a User model.

Comment: Great!!! Thank you very much. I got two objects from same user thats why it create an issue.